# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Chinese_PRC_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I `INNER JOIN tblMachine on b.strMachID = tblMachine.strMachID`

this error appears:

> Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Chinese_PRC_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

What is this error mean? This is my query.

```
select distinct b.strCostCentreID ,  b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, strPayTypeCode, b.strRemarks as Agency, tblMachine.strDesc As KName,
     (SUM(b.dblPaidAmt)) as RM   
     From tblCurrTrxMaster as b INNER JOIN tblMachine on b.strMachID = tblMachine.strMachID  
     WHERE  strPaymentMethod = '02' and (b.dtmCreated>='1/23/2020') AND (strTransStatus='01')
     GROUP BY b.strCostCentreID , b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, b.strPayTypeCode, b.strRemarks ,b.strMachID, tblMachine.strDesc
```

Comment: It means you are trying to compare to string columns with a different collation.Please consult the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15). Ideally you would change one of the collations so they are both the same, otherwise you could end up with performance issues. As a simple fix use the collate keyword in the query to change the collation of one of the columns such that they match.

Comment: yes. i got it. thank you very much, i just removed the "Chinese_PRC_CI_AS" at Table Designer.

Comment: It's best to use the same collation through your organization unless you have a good reason to do otherwise. This attention to detail is important to avoid errors like this. It's difficult to change collation later.

Answer (score 0):

You can force the collation to be used

```
select distinct b.strCostCentreID ,  b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, strPayTypeCode, b.strRemarks as Agency, tblMachine.strDesc As KName,
     (SUM(b.dblPaidAmt)) as RM   
     From tblCurrTrxMaster as b INNER JOIN tblMachine 
    on b.strMachID  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS= tblMachine.strMachID  COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
     WHERE  strPaymentMethod = '02' and (b.dtmCreated>='1/23/2020') AND (strTransStatus='01')
     GROUP BY b.strCostCentreID , b.strPOSOnlineRefNo, b.strPayTypeCode, b.strRemarks ,b.strMachID, tblMachine.strDesc
```